# JDBC executeQuery returns empty ResultSet even though there is data?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false",
                    "root", "password");
            Statement myStamement = myConn.createStatement();
            ResultSet myRs = myStamement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
            while(myRs.next()) {  
                System.out.println("I GOT SOMETHING FROM DATABASE");
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("id"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and I have setup my SQL server and can see the same query in mySQL workbench here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA2Ph.png)

It doesn't give me an error connecting to the database else it would go to catch.
It returns an empty ResultSet else it would go into while loop once.
There is data in my database that I can see from using same command in photo photo.

Comment: Are you sure you committed the data?

Comment: thank you, i am just starting of with databases :)